# File Upload in Rest API yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

my controller file inside api/v1/controller/

```
class ProfileController extends ActiveController
  {
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Profile';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
                'only' => 
                         ['index', 'view', 'createnew','update','search'],
                'formats' => 
                         ['application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,],

            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index' => ['get'],            
                    'view' => ['get'],            
                    'createnew' => ['post'],       
                    'update' => ['put'],         
                    'delete' => ['delete'],        
                    'deleteall' => ['post'],
                    'search' => ['get']
                ],

            ]
        ];
    }

    public function actionCreatenew() {
        $model = new Profile();
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());



        $model->asset = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'asset');
     
        $name = $model->user_id;

        if($model->asset) {
            
          $model->asset->saveAs('uploads/'.$name.'.
                           '.$model->asset->extension);
            $model->asset = $model->asset->name.'.'.
                            $model->asset->extension;
           
        }



        if($model->save()) {
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>"Success",
                     'data'=>$model->attributes),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>"Failure",
                     'error_code'=>400,
                     'errors'=>$model->errors),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to use access this from Postman like:
POST http://localhost/myapp/api/v1/profiles

I get Invalid Parameter – `yii\base\InvalidParamException`

Response content must not be an array.

What is the issue?? help would be grateful!! Thanks

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding this in my api/config.php file ''urlManager' => [ 'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 'enableStrictParsing' => true, 'showScriptName' => false, 'rules' => [ ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/country','v1/profile'], 'extraPatterns' => [ 'POST createnew' => 'createnew', ], ], ], ],'

Answer (score 10):

You can easily receive single / multi-uploaded files using HTTP POST with form-data encoding in Yii2, directly in your Yii2 Controller / action.

Use this code:

```
    $uploads = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName("upfile");
    if (empty($uploads)){
        return "Must upload at least 1 file in upfile form-data POST";
    }

    // $uploads now contains 1 or more UploadedFile instances
    $savedfiles = [];
    foreach ($uploads as $file){
        $path = //Generate your save file path here;
        $file->saveAs($path); //Your uploaded file is saved, you can process it further from here
    }
```

If you use Postman API client to test how your API is working, you can configure the upload endpoint to work like this for multi-file uploads:

[image: Body form-data params for POST data request]

**Note**: The `upfile[]` square brackets are important! Postman will happily let you select multiple files for upload in one slot, but this will not *actually* work. Doing it the way shown in the screenshot makes an array of files available to the Yii2 action, through the `UploadedFile` mechanism. This is roughly equivalent to the standard PHP `$_FILES` superglobal variable but with easier handling.

Single files can be uploaded with or without the `[]` square brackets after the key name. And of course you can name `upfile` whatever you like, for your convention.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('asset');` instead of getInstance() checkout this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065622/uploading-file-in-postman-extension/37076254#37076254)

Comment: Thanks for this(added as you mentioned) .But I'm getting "Response content must not be an array." not for this I believe.

Comment: In which line?  why are you echoing json string? you can simple use
 ``return ['status'=>'success','data'=>$model->attributes];``

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding this in my api/config.php file 
''urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/country','v1/profile'],
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'POST createnew' => 'createnew',
                    ],
                ],

            ],
        ],'